# Gateway Timeout - Nagios Availability Report

Tags: nagios, nagiosxi

I'm trying to fetch Availability Report for 3 months. For 2 months I can able to fetch the Report. But If I set the report for 3 months, Im getting "Gateway TimeOut" issue.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: This is not a programming issue (more likely a server performance/configuration issue). You should ask this question on [su] or, if it's a professional setup, on [sf]

Comment: Do I need to increase any timeout in Nagios or Apache